# Interesting graph traversal optimization problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, graph-theory, genetic-algorithm

Suppose you have a set of nodes connected into a tree structure with one root node and any node may have any number of child nodes.

You can only traverse the tree starting at the root node or from your current position along direct connections. I.e., no random access to a specific node, but the structure of the graph is already known and fits in memory.

Each node has a **must-revisit time** which is not revealed to you. The must-revisit time is calculated [where *i* = time interval since last visit] as **(now + a + *i**b + (*i**c)^2)**. The parameters a, b and c have different values for each node but each will always generally be within the same order of magnitude across different nodes.

If you revisit a node past after its must-revisit time has passed it will reset so that the must-revisit time after that visit is calculated as (now + a) per the formula above. If you traverse to a node it will be revealed to you whether you have past the must-revisit time or not, but you will not know what it was or what the values or a, b or c are.

Your goal is to choose a strategy to traverse to and revisit each node in the tree over time so that no node is past its must-revisit time and **minimize the number of traversal operations** overall. Revisiting a node too early is inefficient, but revisiting a node past its must-revisit time is highly inefficient. Ideally you want to hit each node just before its must-revisit time or if you need to in order to traverse to another node.

Comment: Do we need to worry about the tree changing dynamically?

Comment: No offense, but the english in "If you traverse to a node it will be revealed to you whether you have past the must-revisit time or not, but you will not know what it was or the values or a, b or c." is very much broken. Why won't I know what `a`, `b` and `c` were? Aren't they part of the node? Can you please clarify this? This seems to contradict the next paragraph, because if we are to visit each node before its must-revisit time, we must have access to all the must-revisit times.

Comment: @IVlad: you don't have access to that information because that's the challenge of the problem. Some other system has that information that you have limited access to. You only have access to a boolean that specifies whether the must-revisit time has elapsed as of when you traversed to this node.

Comment: @Kathy: you can assume not if that makes the problem easier

Comment: If you don't have access to the values of `a`, `b` and `c` of each node, I don't see how you can guarantee that you visit each node in time. You're basically flying blind.

Comment: @IVlad guaranteeing may not be possible. It's an optimization problem. It may require a genetic or learning algorithm. How can you get as close as you can?

Comment: Sounds like homework... Is it?

Comment: The way that the problem is currently stated, the optimal strategy is to never move.

Since the *"interval since the last visit"* **i** is always increasing, and the *"must-revisit time"* increases like **i<sup>2</sup>**, eventually the must-revisit time will surpass the current time *(even if **c** is negative, since it is included inside the square)*.  By standing still, eventually no node will be past its must-revisit time, now and forever.

Comment: There are (at least) two points that are very unclear about this question. 1) How is must-revisit time calculated? If a node has {a=1,b=2,c=3} and I visit it at t=5, how much time to I have to visit it again? 2) *What* am I trying to minimize? Does the game end once I visit all nodes soon enough, or do I continue, trying to find the shortest path?

Comment: @ʞɔıu - if you can reset the game and play it under the same parameters multiple times, then you can use a genetic algorithm where the population encodes permutations of the node labels, which stand for ways of traversing the tree. Your ranking function sorts by number of nodes that are past the revisit time and by total number of traversals in case of equality. Keep playing the game until you find a solution you're happy with. If the tree is small enough, you can just brote force it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why `a`, `b` and `c` are unknown. If they are unknown then it seems that the best heuristic is the traveling salesman problem, which is NP-Complete. So maybe I'm misunderstanding something.